# How to expose Amazon EC2 instance's process states

Tags: c#, java, python, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I'm using Amazon EC2 instances for multiple processes with various states. It's important for reporting and analysis that an instances state can be accessed at any time. So far I've thought of three options.

1. Publish this state via an HTTP endpoint or webservice
2. Add and update instance tags for the different processes and their states
3. Use instance metadata. I'm not sure if this requires SimpleDB to be used.

Out of these, only 1 and 3 are options I like. Choice 2 is just not what AWS instance tags should be used for. 3 is the option I like the most.

So I ask, how would I go about option 3? Do I need to use SimpleDB to accomplish it? Has anyone found any Amazon docs on how to create instance metadata?

I also want to leave this question open ended, so if anyone disagrees with option 3 please make a case.

Comment: just as an idea: you can submit custom metrics to CloudWatch (see http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/index.html?publishingMetrics.html)

Comment: The true EC2 instance meta-data is read only. However, you can store data about an instance state wherever you want and call it meta-data. SimpleDB is a fine place to store it.  One condition you'll need to consider is how to clean up the data when  an instance terminates or fails.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Instance meta-data. There are many ways to store that meta-data like in database, file system etc.
Check this documentation: 
[Using Instance Metadata](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html)

Amazon EC2 instance has associated meta-data, as well as user data supplied at the time of  launching the instance. The meta and user data is instance-specific, and therefore only accessible to the instance. One of the most useful data is user-data, which can be used to pass configuration information or even initialization scripts to the instance upon launch.